# Equality of subgroups $H \subseteq K \subseteq G$ with the same finite index in $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $G$ be a group and let $H,K$ be two subgroups of $G$ such that $H\subseteq K$and $[G:H] = [G:K]$ is finite. Prove that $H = K$.

Can somebody please give me some idea to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$H$ is a subgroup of $K$, so consider $K/H$, the set of cosets of $H$ in $K$. This set is finite because $[K:H] = [G:H]/[G:K]$. Moreover, if $[G:H] = [G:K]$ then this forces $[K:H] = 1$, so $K=H$.

Comment: @user1729: But I'm not dividing by infinity; it's given in the problem statement that $[G:H]$ and $[G:K]$ are finite.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, I was slightly confused!